# Is there Visual Studio intellisense support for jQuery 1.4.3?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

Is there intellisense support in Visual Studio for jQuery 1.4.3? How do I enable it? What file(s) do I need?

Comment: "Please give detailed description" - samesies.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. How can this be off-topic?

Comment: Please add relevant tags, and write out "Visual Studio". Acronyms can be confusing in a multi-platform and -language community.

Comment: Check this article. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx

Comment: @Pekka웃 Slight abuse of the "Close-off-topic", no? Sure, the question could have more tags and the English could be better, but grammar, spelling abbr. netiquette aside, it's bang ON topic.

Comment: @Robino yeah, doesn't look really justified in hindsight.

Answer (score 4):

AppendTo has released a vsdoc file for jQuery 1.4.3
http://appendto.com/blog/2010/11/visual-studio-2010-vsdoc-jquery-143-now-available

Answer (score 1):

You need to either reference or have in the same folder the corresponding vsdoc file with jQuery

Download [this Visual Studio Patch](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736) to enable vsdoc support.

Download [the latest supported vsdoc file for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery). Looks like support stops at 1.4.1

Read More here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

Comment: It looks like the latest version with vsdoc is 1.4.1